# Where to do I find my saved book files on my root device?

Tags: applications, rooting, adb, settings, usb

I have a book app that downloads book files from the Internet. It stops working and the developer wants me to root my phone and find those downloaded files for him so that he can debug.

I've rooted my device and have ssh onto my rooted device. I made myself a root by "su" so there is nothing that I can't access. The problem is that I have no idea where those book files are saved physically. It must be somewhere because I can view those books on my phone.

It would be good if I can use the "find ..." unix command, but my Android device doesn't have the "find" installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to settings->Apps->Your app->move to SD Card. Then follow these steps:

1. First download ES File explorer
2. Search for the app's folder on the SD card.
3. If you cannot, go to the Android folder->DATA->Your app.
                     OR
4. go to Android->OBB->your app.

If you cannot find the folder, the developer ought to help you, especially since you are helping him.